# Why only map and reduce functions in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, distributed-computing

Are there any particular reasons why we have only two functions `map()` and `reduce()` in this MapReduce concept of distributed processing?? Why wasn't the Hadoop framework designed to be generic, allowing the user to make as many function calls as he desires after the initial mapping function?

Comment: I guess it had to be called "MapReduce" for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to apply different **Reduce** operations for a given **Map** output, I would just use `MultipleOutputs` to write to different files/directories, this would "simulate" having multiple types of reducers on the same map output. You can apply your `MultipleOutputs` in the `Reducer`, more information can be found [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html).

The goal of having a single Map and Reduce function is so that this can be easily parallelized across a wide range of machines. A Map/Reduce job is a single process that is parallelized, it doesn't really make sense IMO to try to apply several operations on the same data, if you need that you can probably extend your Reducer with what I wrote above, or write another job.

Answer (score 1):

While Charles' answer explains the reason behind the MapReduce concept, you can very well *make as many function calls as you desire after the initial mapping function* just by overriding the `run()` of the `Mapper` class (New API)

```
  @override
  public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
      map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
    }
    // Call all your methods you want here
    cleanup(context);
  }
```

You can do the similar thing in the reducer too.

Comment: did you actually try this??

Comment: Cool..just curious about use cases when such a thing is needed.

Comment: You want to generate a single report file. There will be single reducer. Now, you do some aggregations in reduce(), and then print them after all the reduce() are called by calling your own separate method which would create a pdf report file locally and then move that file to s3.